# SSRS drilldown where parent is repeated in detail group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, grouping

I am trying to show a hierarchical (drilldown) report, that repeats detail data from the parent total in the child groups. E.g. a salespeople hierarchy, where each salesperson can generate sales and have group members:

-- **Person 1: total sales 10**
---- Person 1: 2
---- Person 2: 3
---- **Person 3: total sales 5**
------ Person 3: 2
------ Person 4: 3

Person 1 and 3 in this example are group leads and the total sales displayed in their row includes sales produced directly by them as well as sales produced by salespeople in their group. Therefore, to properly show where the sales came from, person 1 must also be displayed like a group member (same - one level below - for person 3).

The data source is an SQL query. I tried several row grouping options and tried to deliver the data as a nested set or put the levels into separate columns but I could not figure out another way to get this done than to preformat the data in a complicated SQL query - I was hoping their is a more SSRS-like way to accomplish this.

Example hierarchical data:

```
DECLARE @salespeople TABLE (SpID INT, ParentID INT);
DECLARE @sales TABLE (SpID INT, Amount INT);

INSERT INTO @salespeople (SpID, ParentID) VALUES
(1, NULL),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 2);

INSERT INTO @sales (SpID, Amount) VALUES
(1, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 2),
(4, 3);

WITH rowgroup
AS
(
    SELECT ParentID, sp.SpId, s.Amount
    FROM @salespeople sp
    JOIN @sales s ON sp.SpID = s.SpID
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sp.ParentID, sp.SpId, s.Amount
    FROM @salespeople sp
    JOIN @sales s ON sp.SpID = s.SpID
    JOIN rowgroup r ON r.SpID = sp.ParentID
)
SELECT * FROM rowgroup;
```

Comment: When you say drilldown, do you actually mean an SSRS drilldown scenario (i.e. a toggle item to show/hide rows) or just as a synonym for grouping? Also, what does your Dataset look like - what is the relationship between rows? Can you add some sample data?

Comment: Yes, actual drilldown, i.e. only person 1 would be initially visible in the example with total sales of ten. When I drill into person 1, I can see that an amount of 2 was produced be person 1 itself and 3 be person 2 and 5 by person 3, which itself can be drilled into.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use a table to insert the **details**: SPID and **s.
   Amount**
2. Then you would ** Addd Group** Row by right clicking on the
   detail row from above and selecting add **parent group**.  It will
   prompt you to **group by** and you would select **PID**
3. You could then play with the **visibility** to allow a drill down, so
   when you generate the report all the detail rows will be **hidden** and
   you could click on the **parent group row** in order to show the
   details.  Like what you have.

This should be a good start, I don't know what your data set look like, I can help you further if you provide that.